# Singular Value Decomposistion Padding an image with 0's

Tags: matlab, svd

I am working with SVD, using two images,image1 dimensions is 512x512 and image2 dimensions is 240x470. I am getting error in the lines of code below because images are not of the same size. I know there is a way I can pad out image2 with 0's? But I am unsure of how to go about this? Can anyone help please? I am using Matlab.

```
[Uh,Sh,Vh]= svd(image1);

[Uw,Sw,Vw]= svd(double(image2));

Shw = Sh + a * Sw;
VhT=transpose(Vh);
Ihw= Uh*Shw*VhT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Try

```
image2_padded = padarray(image2, [136 21]);
```

for symmetric padding (136 zeros at the top and at the bottom, 21 zeros at left and at right). See [`padarray` documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) for further options.